# I tried to create a TriangleWord java but code doesn't return a result,,, In need of assistance

Tags: java

I am trying to make a word triangle in nested for loops for an assignment and I can't seem to understand why this code does not work. The inner loop is where I'm lost in.

```
  String word;
  Scanner kbreader = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
  word = kbreader.next();
  int i;      for (int i = 0; i <= word.length(); i--)
  {
        System.out.print(" ");
  }
  word.substring(0,i);
     for (int j = i; j <= 1; j++)
  {   
        System.out.print(j);
  }
  System.out.println();
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
Enter a word: hippo

hippo
hipp
hip
hi
h
```

Comment: you don't have nested for-loop, instead 2 different for-loop.

Comment: Your current code doesn't compile, please edit your question to show your actual running code, and explain exactly what "does not work" means.

Comment: You can use the debugger to see exactly what's happening, or just print out the value of `i` each time around the first loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to do :

- i) There is no need of nested for loops. Nested for loops means one
  loop inside another. In your present code example, it is one for loop
  after another for loop.

Also you have to iterate the loop from the end and not from the start to use the substring function. Your current code also gives **compile time error** as you are declaring 2 variables of the same name ,i. Thus, we wont declare it it for the second time in the for loop and simply use it after you declared it above the for loop.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String word;
      Scanner kbreader = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
      word = kbreader.next();
      int i;  
      for ( i = word.length(); i >=0; i--)
      {
          System.out.println(word.substring(0,i));
      
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    
}
```

This code gives the following output

```
Enter a word: 
hippo
hippo
hipp
hip
hi
h
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this problem a while ago. I think the exact issue you're running into (based off of your code snippet) is that a) the for loops aren't actually nested, and b) you really don't need nested for loops to solve this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < thing1; i++){
    System.out.println("This code will run less than the other");
    for(int j = 0; j < thing2; j++){
        System.out.println("This code will run more than the other");
    }
}
```

This is the general way to set up nested for loops. However, for your problem, I think you want just 1 for loop. Consider this logic:

```
String word = "hippo";

for(int i = word.length(); i > 0; i--){
    System.out.println(word.substring(0,i));
}
```

Which solves the original problem.